# node.js does not start via upstart (but does when manually run from command line)

Tags: node.js, upstart

I have a node.js app that I can run successfully from the command line. I'd like to run it using Upstart.

I'm seeing a `[ReferenceError: requirejs is not defined]` when it hits the first line of my app, which is...

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
```

The exec line from my upstart script looks like

```
exec sudo -u pi /usr/local/bin/node /home/[my_app_dir]/myapp.js >> /var/log/myapp.log 2>&1
```

PATH not being set correctly?

Comment: as an immediate unrelated reaction, you don't want to be `sudo`ing a node process, node and npm have been written to run entirely in non-root user space

Comment: Was under the impression all upstart jobs had to run with sudo permissions and then you could change the user using the -u arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's more likely it's looking in the wrong place for resolving `node_modules`. Do a cd (relevant dir) followed by `node myapp >> ...` instead, and it should be able to find all your required libraries.

Comment: Yup, wrapping the exec in a `script` block that chdir's to the correct directory seems to work. Thanks. For future knowledge, any applicable nodejs environment variables I can set to work around this?

Comment: hmm, not that I know of. Node simply checks the `node_modules` dir in the working directory, then if it finds nothing, goes up 1 dir, and keeps doing that until it hits root or is denied access to the higher dir.